# lodash: how to zip an array of objects with values

Tags: javascript, dictionary, zip, lodash

I'm looking how to zip an array of objects with values including a new key for each value using lodash. Tried with [zip](https://lodash.com/docs#zip), [zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) and [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) but I don't find the key.

What I want to do is the following (avoiding to iterate manually over the arrays)

```js
   const array = [
     {a: 3, b: 42}, 
     {c: 4}, 
     {d: 12}
   ]
   const values = ['these', 'are', 'new', 'values']

   // goal = foo(array, values) <<< HERE
   goal = [
     {a: 3, b: 42, v: 'these'}, 
     {c: 4, v: 'are'},
     {d: 12, v:'new'}
   ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [zipWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#zipWith) to provide a custom iteratee:

```
var newArray = _.zipWith(array, values, function(item, value) {
    return _.defaults({ v: value }, item);
});
```

Note that this approach *doesn't* mutate the original `array`.

Comment: > this approach doesn't mutate the original array :thumbsup:

Answer (score 4):

You can use the native [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. See the below snippet.

If you want to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to do this, you can just do the same thing except with `_.map(array, function (item, index) {...});`.

```js
var array = [
  {a: 3, b: 42}, 
  {c: 4}, 
  {d: 12}
];
var values = ['this', 'are', 'new', 'values']
 
var goal = array.map(function (item, index) {
  item.v = values[index];
  return item;
});

document.getElementById('goal').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(goal);
```

```html
<div id="goal"></div>
```