# Combine multiple arrays using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to search for away to Combine arrays together and returns an object using lodash ex:

```
var names = ['Franko','Dalia','Peter','Max']
var products = ['Mobile','Tv','Camera']
var result = [{
     'name':'Franko'
     'product':'Mobile'
},{
     'name':'Dalia'
     'product':'Tv'
},{
     'name':'Peter'
     'product':'Camera'
},{
     'name':'Max'
     'product':''
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash: how to zip an array of objects with values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34309220/lodash-how-to-zip-an-array-of-objects-with-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost like the duplicate suggested by Mike C, but with slightly different details, use [`zipWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#zipWith):

```js
var names = ['Franko','Dalia','Peter','Max'];
var products = ['Mobile','Tv','Camera'];

var result = _.zipWith(names, products, function(name, product) {
    return {name: name, product: product || ''};
  });

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple pure JS solution here...

```js
var names = ['Franko','Dalia','Peter','Max'],
 products = ['Mobile','Tv','Camera'],
   zipped = names.map((e,i) =>  ({name: e, product: products[i] || ""}));
console.log(zipped);
```

Comment: That's fragile. What would happen if `products` is longer than `names`? (P.S. if you're using ES2015 features, please stop using `var`)

Comment: @Amit It won't go any further than `names` array length.

Comment: ... hence it's fragile.

Comment: @Amit According to the given data it is pretty solid. OP does not show products getting assigned to undefined names. Otherwise it is just a simple task to call map upon the longer array.

Comment: According to the given data you don't need any function or logic, the `result` is already there. When you propose an algorithm / code snippet to solve a problem, it should be solid and complete, not fragile to minor input changes. Saying "*it is just a simple task...*" isn't any better - improve your answer if you think (agree?) it's lacking.