# merging two array objects using loadash

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can anyone help me in merging of two array of objects please using loadash in javascript? Below is the example arrays. I tried with _merge

```
arr 1= [
    {
        "areaId": 1,
        "areaName": "areanam222",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1
    },
    {
        "areaId": 2,
        "areaName": "arename",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1
    }
]

arr2 =[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BN",

    }
]


arrResult =[
    {
        "areaId": 1,
        "areaName": "areanam222",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BN"    
    }, {
        "areaId": 2,
        "areaName": "arename",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BN"
    }
]
```

I tried with below option but it is returning only one record.

```
var arrResult =   _(list).keyBy('businessExecutiveId').merge(_.keyBy(this.typeaheadDataList, 'id')).values() .value();
```

I also tried with below
const c = _.assign([], arr1, arr2);

reslut I am getting is like below

{
    id: 1,
    name: "BN"
},
{
    areaId: 1,
    areaName: "ASas",
    businessExecutiveId: 1,
    id: 1,
    name: "BN"
}

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple arrays using loadash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821558/combine-multiple-arrays-using-loadash)

Comment: What are you trying to do: use the `businessExecutiveId` from `arr1` to look up an object from `arr2`, or take every combination of an object from `arr1` and an object from `arr2`?  Giving an example where `arr2` contains more than one object would make it clear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I am looking is I need to merge arrays based on businessExecutiveid in arr1 with id in arr2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash to do this. Why not just use javascripts `reduce` function to merge all object keys from arr2 objects into the objects of array 1, like so

```js
arr1.reduce((arr, obj) => {
 const newObj = arr2.reduce((o, insideObj) => ({
  ...o,
  ...insideObj
 }), obj)

 return [...arr, newObj]
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I am looking is I need to merge arrays matched based on businessExecutiveid in arr1 with id in arr2.

Answer (score 0):

If we had [array comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), we could have used something like this:

```
[
   for (a of arr1) 
   for (b of arr2) 
   if(a.businessExecutiveId === b.id) {...a, ...b}
]
```

Without array comprehension, we use flatMap:

```
_(arr1).flatMap(a =>
  _(arr2).flatMap(b => 
    a.businessExecutiveId === b.id ? [{...a, ...b}] : []        
  ).value()        
).value()
```

```js
var arr1= [
    {
        "areaId": 1,
        "areaName": "areanam222",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1
    },
    {
        "areaId": 2,
        "areaName": "arename",
        "businessExecutiveId": 1
    },
    {
        "areaId": 3,
        "areaName": "bname",
        "businessExecutiveId": 2
    }
]

var arr2= [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "BN",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "CM",
    }
]

res = _(arr1).flatMap(a =>
  _(arr2).flatMap(b => 
    a.businessExecutiveId === b.id ? [{...a, ...b}] : []        
  ).value()        
).value()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved it by using below code.                          
    _.map(list, function(item) {

    return _.merge(item, _.find(temp, function(o) {return o.id  == item.businessExecutiveId }) );
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr1.reduce((arr, obj) => {
 const newObj = arr2.reduce((o, insideObj) => ({
  ...o,
  ...insideObj
 }), obj)

 return [...arr, newObj]
}, [])
```

I resolved it by using below code.

```
_.map(list, function(item) {

    return _.merge(item, _.find(temp, function(o) {return o.id  == item.businessExecutiveId }) );
});
```